# CreateNamedPipe causes ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED?

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

i need to create a named pipe for communication between client and server (in same host), here is the code:

```
WCHAR wszPipeName[MAX_FILE_LENGTH];
swprintf_s(wszPipeName, MAX_FILE_LENGTH, L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TEST%d", uniqueID);
pipe = CreateNamedPipe(
           wszPipeName, // name of the pipe
           PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
       PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_NOWAIT,
       1,
           MAX_MSG_SIZE, 
           MAX_MSG_SIZE , //inbound buffer
           MAX_READ_DATA_TIMEOUT,
           NULL // use default security attributes
       );
```

It the handler get back is always INVALID_HANDLE_VAULE, and the error is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Is there anything wrong here? It is running on Windows 7/8.

Thanks

Comment: Any help? *All instances of a named pipe must specify the same pipe type (byte-type or message-type), pipe access (duplex, inbound, or outbound), instance count, and time-out value. If different values are used, this function fails and GetLastError returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.* Also, I've only used that like once, but shouldn't you have at least 2 instances of your pipe as the max when two processes are using it?

Comment: This is for server side, just create the named pipe.... Right now, i can't even make the createNamePipe function work.

Comment: what is the name of your pipe? specifically what is contained in wszPipeName? Your code looks good.

Comment: Is it a local pipe? I.e.` L"\\\\.\\pipe\\your\\pipe\\name\\goes\\here"`? Or more succinctly `L"\\\\.\\pipe\\yourpipename"` if you prefer. Note: the double back-ticks are to escape back-ticks in the string literal, if that is what you're passing as your pipe name.

Comment: Yes, a local pipe. The name is 
swprintf_s(wszPipeName, MAX_FILE_LENGTH, L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TEST%d", uniqueID);

Comment: have you tried with another name?

Comment: What are the values for MAX_MSG_SIZE and MAX_READ_DATA_TIMEOUT?  I've just tried your code and it works for me.  It's also possible some other process is using the name of pipe you want.

Comment: Yea, I tried other name. But still doesn't work :(

Comment: Try use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to trace `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` operation. Look at stack which system component involved in the an access denied.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the reason, it is because the security limitation. After providing a suitable security descriptor, it just works!

Comment: Could you provide more information about what "suitable security descriptor" you used? (I may be running into a similar issue: when I run the program that creates the named pipe as Administrator, it works, but when I run the program as a normal user, I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.)

Comment: @izbob, could you please share your solutions with the community

Comment: as i commented, eventually,  providing a suitable security descriptor resolved the issue, it is because of the security.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't explain what is "suitable". 

Answer (score 0):

This is Python code, but this sets up a security descriptor for the local user and denies remote:

```
dacl = ACL()

# Deny NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SID
sid = CreateWellKnownSid(WinNetworkSid)
dacl.AddAccessDeniedAce(ACL_REVISION, GENERIC_ALL, sid)

# Allow current user SID
token = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY)
sid = GetTokenInformation(token, TokenUser)[0]
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ACL_REVISION, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, sid)

security_descriptor = SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR()
security_descriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(True, dacl, False)

security_attributes = SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
security_attributes.SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR = security_descriptor

pipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    <your other params here>
    security_attributes
)
```